# pandas sort with smaller memory footprint?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas Series (50 million+) that I need to sort with 32-bit Python, but I am getting a MemoryError during the sort. It appears that pandas' sort algorithm makes several temporary arrays during the sort. I know I can use numpy's sort algorithm instead, but is there an alternate sort algorithm in the pandas API that I can use that has a smaller memory footprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 possibilites

1) This is essentially what sort does, but doesn't use temporaries (note if you have NaN anywhere this will not work)

```
In [1]: s = Series(np.random.rand(10))

In [3]: np.argsort(s.values)
Out[3]: array([8, 0, 1, 3, 9, 6, 2, 7, 5, 4])

In [4]: s[np.argsort(s.values)]
Out[4]: 
8    0.033948
0    0.183882
1    0.236021
3    0.372763
9    0.383721
6    0.489090
2    0.498036
7    0.676246
5    0.709906
4    0.738510
dtype: float64
```

2) This is not yet implemented, but you could write to a HDFStore table; there is a readSorted method to read it back in sorted order. try method 1), if that doesn't work, then I can give you a small script to do this I think

Comment: Thanks no need to write small scipt, I can do it.